# where is the correct place to glEnableVertexAttribArray

Tags: opengl, graphics, mesh, opengl-3, opengl-4

Quick question: I've always seen VAO meshes enable theire vertex attribute arrays inside the 'draw' call in such a way:

```
void draw() {
    bindVAO();
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0 ... 3);
    glDrawElements(...);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0 ... 3);
    unbindVAO();
}
```

I've also noticed that I could outright omit the second half down from the Draw Elements call as such:

```
void draw() {
    bindVAO();
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0 ... 3);
    glDrawElements(...);
}
```

Similarly I moved the `glEnableVertexAttribArray()` calls to the mesh generation/loading function, and everything seems to run fine.

I was wondering if all of this was legal,  and if there was a reason why many pieces of sample code (or other things of such nature) have the attribute arrays enabled and disabled next to the draw call (surely doing it every frame/draw cycle is a waste of time).

Comment: The reason you see this is that there are a lot of bad examples online. And then people start copying them, and create even more of them. Not having to call these functions before each draw call is the main purpose of using VAOs in the first place.

Comment: @Reto Koradi yeah that's what I figured XD, preferred to ask anyways.

Comment: The VAO stores this state, so you could use a VAO with all of the state setup. Or you can bind the VAO and then constantly change the state every time you draw, both are correct but the VAO is going to remember any changes you make (and you may not).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using VAOs *and* within a single VAO do not change the buffer bindings, then tying `glEnableVertexAttribArray` to VAO creation and update is perfectly fine, and recommended.

However if no VAO is used or bindings within a VAO are changed dynamically, then placing `glEnableVertexAttribArray` close to the binding code (which is usually happening in drawing, then) is a better fit.